# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'test' resolved to null

Tags: jsf-2.2

I am building a small hello world JSF application.

My index.xhtml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<body>
    Hello user.
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{test.value}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Enter" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My welcome.xhtml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<body>
    <h2>Welcome #{test.value}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

My managed bean is as follows

```
package com.test.testclass;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Test {
    private String value;


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

My web.xml is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

        <display-name>Test Project</display-name>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
            <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- Welcome page -->
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <!-- Faces Servlet -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>

My gradle build file is as follows

buildscript {
    // Repositories for libraries needed for building:
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'war'
}

war {
    webInf {
        from "WebContent/WEB-INF"
    }
    from("WebContent") {
        include "index.xhtml"
    }
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        url "http://repository.primefaces.org/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    def jsfApi = "javax.faces:javax.faces-api:2.2"
    def atmosphereRuntime = "org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:2.4.9"

    compile \
        jsfApi,
        atmosphereRuntime

    providedCompile \
        "javax:javaee-api:7.0",
        "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0", 
        "org.glassfish:javax.json:1.+"
}

task deploy(type: Copy) {
    description "Deploys the test application."
    from war.outputs
    into System.env.DEPLOY_DIR
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

I am getting the following error when I enter a string in the index page and hit enter

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: /index.xhtml @9,38 value="#{test.value}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'test' resolved to null
root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @9,38 value="#{test.value}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'test' resolved to null
root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'test' resolved to null
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the "" logs.

""
```

The backend bean is set to null somehow. What am I doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Out of curiosity... Did you in no way when using a search engine found any of the duplicates that are all duplicated by the same Q that yours is a duplicate of?

Comment: OH and please switch to using CDI managed beans instead of JSF managed ones... And JSF-2.2+ namespace declarations in the xhtml files